# Was "blue death" a popular term for Cholera in the US in the1800s?

Tags: etymology, expressions, phrase-requests, american-english, phrase-meaning

I'm working on my dissertation on public health. I just came across Robert Morris' book on Cholera called, "The Blue Death". My university library doesn't have access to the book and both Amazon & Google Book previews won't show any internal text. Now, I understand WHY cholera would be called "blue death" -- skin turns bluish gray in most cholera victims (and most diseases got their names from their physical appearance, e.g. jaundice = yellow fever; small spots/pustules/pock marks = smallpox, etc.)

I'm just trying to figure out who was the first to refer to cholera as "blue death" and if this was a popular phrase in 19C America.

AND if there could be any connection between the French word "morbleu" and cholera as "blue death".

I joined this site to ask this question after I came across the "blue murder" thread that makes mention of "morbleu" too. Here's that thread: [Why does one scream blue murder?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8875/why-does-one-scream-blue-murder)

Comment: Define "popular". Here's [an NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+Blue+Death%2CThe+Black+Death&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThe%20Blue%20Death%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThe%20Black%20Death%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CThe%20Blue%20Death%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThe%20Black%20Death%3B%2Cc0) showing that **The Blue Death** practically "flatlines" by comparison with **The Black Death**. And the only period when the former registers on the chart at all is 10-15 years ago (Haiti?) - it was comparatively unknown before that.

Comment: [**scream blue murder**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scream_blue_murder#:~:text=From%20French%20morbleu%20(%E2%80%9Cgadzooks%2C,%E2%80%9Cdeath%20of%20God%E2%80%9D).) *From French morbleu (“gadzooks, zounds”, interjection) (archaic), from mort bleu (“blue death”), a minced oath of mort Dieu (“death of God”).* Nothing to do with blue death or cholera.

Comment: I managed to crack that book ('The Blue Death' by *Robert Morris*) for you. You can download it by pressing the ['Download' button here](https://www.zamzar.com/uploadComplete.php?convertFile=epub&to=pdf&session=ad79177b9e6ca3fba74ae8b1929c5ee&email=false&tcs=Z75)

Comment: Google Books evidence of the 19th c. usage examples suggests rare instances in the USA and just  a few in BrE. Other cases are false positives.   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+Blue+Death&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true&direct_url=t4%3B%2CThe%20Blue%20Death%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20blue%20death%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20Blue%20Death%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20Blue%20Death%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20blue%20death%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This interesting question has drawn an excellent answer, and yet it appears to be on the verge of being closed by by review queue voters (I voted to keep it open, but to my surprise the count is now 1 stay open to 3 close). How is this not an on-topic question? Are we unable to tell by checking historical sources whether a term appears frequently or rarely in the written record?

Comment: @SvenYargs, I added my stay open vote. Don't you have the golden hammer? Or am I misunderstanding how that badge works?

Comment: @JEL: The wielder of a so-called golden hammer can, with a single swing, close a question that he or she considers to be a duplicate—but the hammer is strictly an offensive weapon. You can't use it to protect good questions from closure, and (I believe) you can't use it to close faulty questions for reasons other than "duplicate." Not that I would want to. The first time I voted to close some idiom-tagged question as a duplicate, I was shocked that the question closed immediately. It's disconcerting to have that kind of Midas touch, even in a very small realm.

Comment: Thanks, @SvenYargs. I found the Meta question you answered about this. Regrettably, your suggestion was never acted upon (or even acknowledged, so far as I can tell).

Answer (score 2):

January 13, [1832](https://www.browningscorrespondence.com/chronology/), Elizabeth Barrett Browning published a poem she called "The Pestilence" in *[The Times](https://www.newspapers.com/image/32863091/?terms=%22blue%2Bdeath%22)* (London, paywalled). In it, she describes cholera as "the cold blue death". Among the US papers and magazines that soon reprinted "The Pestilence" was the *Philadelphia Album* of 21 Apr [1832](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=umn.31951002807808u&view=1up&seq=134&size=300&q1=blue%20death).

Those, 13 Jan and 21 Apr 1832, are the earliest uses I have found of 'blue death' in the sense of "death from cholera", in the UK and US respectively. In a *Lancaster Examiner* (Lancaster, Pennsylvania; paywalled) article published 28 Jun [1832](https://www.newspapers.com/image/558782822/?terms=%22blue%2Bdeath%22), titled "The Cholera", James B. Kirk, MD, observes

> Blueness has been said generally to characterize this stage [of cholera]; but in this country that is not the fact. The skin of the hands and face is brownish, not blue.

Aside from occasional reprintings of Browning's "The Pestilence", the next use of 'blue death' to mean "cholera death" in the US seems to have been in the Nov [1849](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=pst.000066651857&view=1up&seq=393&size=150&q1=blue%20death) edition of *The Ladies Repository*, in a piece called "Fugitive Letters", by Vindex:

> The cholera's blue death, the thirst, the famine, and the scalping knife, will meet them on the way, and thin their ranks.

Use of the term 'blue death' in the relevant sense in US publications next appears in early October, 1867. The *Evening Star* (Washington, District of Columbia, p 1 col 7) of 03 Oct [1867](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1867-10-03/ed-1/seq-1/#date1=1777&sort=date&date2=1963&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=5&words=blue+death&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=blue+death&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) reprints what was to become a widely reprinted blurb from the *New York Post*:

> It is curious to note the distinctions of color as applied to disease. There are the yellow fever, the black vomit, the green sickness, the white swelling, the scarlet fever, the yellow jaundice, and, as Mrs. Partington says, the "brown creeters." And now we have, as climax, the "blue death," on board the hospital ship at quarantine.

I found no further evidence of 'blue death' in the sense of "cholera death" in US publications through the later decades of the nineteenth century, and no evidence at all of any use of the expletive "Blue Death!", derived from French *mortbleu*, connected with death by cholera.

---

About *The Blue Death*, by Dr. Robert D. Morris: digitized versions of the [2007](https://archive.org/details/bluedeathdisease0000morr/mode/2up) hardcover and [2008](https://archive.org/details/bluedeathintrigu0000morr/mode/2up) softcover editions are available at [*Internet Archive*](https://archive.org/details/texts?and%5B%5D=the%20blue%20death%20morris&sin=) for free checkout (after registration).

Comment: There is also a mention of "the blue death" in a William Herbert's "[The Christian](https://books.google.com/books?id=xHaRxR0hse8C&pg=PA13&dq=%22the+blue+death%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDr5ybzsruAhWfHTQIHTpHAJgQ6AEwAnoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20blue%20death%22&f=false)" (1846): "Pour'd **the blue death** on Mississippi's swamp, / And there join'd hand with that angelic curse, / Who from hot Gambia to Manhattan's mart / Spreads wide the yellow plague." It's not clear what "lurid pestilence" the poet means by "the blue death," but cholera seems a reasonable possibility.

Comment: @SvenYargs Interesting. Westward from the Ganges certainly suggests the historic movement of major cholera outbreaks. Arriving Irish refugees, fleeing *an Gorta Mór*, are associated with outbreaks in the US and Canada, circa 1845.

Comment: @SvenYargs, at first I wondered how I missed (horrors!) the Herbert use. As it turns out, it was published in London, and written by the Dean of Manchester. My answer focuses on US use, as per the question; there might be many UK uses of the term I didn't mention.